# Access values of other rows for matrix manipulation

Tags: arrays, matrix, sas, iterator

I am trying to write a SAS macro to calculate [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) (without using the built-in SAS/IML library).

Since the formula requires to access at the same time values from different rows, I don't know how to implement it.

My idea is to use a DO LOOP on all rows. Inside the loop, a DATA STEP in order to get the values and put them into a global array variable.

Is this the right approach?

```
%DO j=1 %TO &nobs.;
    DATA _null_;
        SET &in_data.;
        IF _n_=&j.;
            CALL symput(CATS("corr_value", _n_), Corr);
    RUN;
    %PUT j=&j. corr_value=&corr_value&j.;
%END;
```

By the way, the above code has several problems, because I get

> WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference CORR_VALUE not resolved.

Moreover, I am not sure the scope of the variable `corr_value` is global, as I have defined it.

**Ref:**

- [Cholesky decomposition - Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)
- [Cholesky Decomposition: Matrix Decomposition - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cholesky-decomposition-matrix-decomposition/)

Comment: The idea of stuffing actual numbers into strings stored in macro variables is ridiculous.  But your problem is simply a missing &.  You are trying to access CORR_VALUE  when you really wanted to access CORR_VALUE1, CORR_VALUE2, etc.  Use `&&core_value&j`.

Comment: @Tom, better ideas are more than welcome. Anyway thanks your correction, it solved the problem, and the variables can be accessed even out of that DO LOOP as wanted

Comment: Load the data into a multidimensional temporary array instead?

Comment: @Reeza,  but how can I access the values from outside DATA STEP?

Comment: You cannot, but you can manipulate it more easily within a data step and it would be in memory so faster, which is usually part of the goal of Cholesky decomposition IMO.

Comment: You never need, or want, to access the DATA outside of a DATA or PROC step.

Comment: It should be straight forward to translate the FORTRAN code in your first reference to a SAS data step.